# Linear Algebra: Check my work?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Task: Find a matrix where the kernel is a subspace of the range. My initial thought was highly simplistic, which makes me double back and think twice. I would love it if someone could point out any mistakes or tell me if I'm right. The matrix I had in mind:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

In this case, we see that the kernel is made up of a single vector, namely the zero vector, as that's the only solution that maps to the zero object. Next, we see that the columns are made up of linearly independent vectors. This means that the column space spans the entire $\mathbb R^3$. The zero vector can be easily shown to be a subspace of the vector space.

Comment: Just a note: in your example, the fact that the columns are linearly independent is more important to make sure that the nullspace contains *only* the zero vector. The zero vector would be in the range of a square matrix even if the columns were not independent. Can you find a less trivial example?

Comment: Would a less trivial example be any matrix with a full rank with one or two free columns? This creates a column space of the entire vector space, but guarantees that the null space is a single vector (line) or two vectors (plane). But what about for 3x3 matrices strictly?

Comment: A less trivial example would require that the nullspace contains more than just the zero vector and in turn that the original matrix is rank deficient.

Comment: In terms of geometry, would that be similar to seeing a line or a plane in the third dimension?

Answer (score 1):

maybe easier to think in terms of a basis, say $e_j$ with $1 \le j \le n$. then consider a map $T$ satisfying:
$$
Te_1 =0 
$$
and for $k \gt 1$
$$
Te_k = e_{k-1}
$$

Comment: Thank you! I had to think about this for awhile, but I think I got it! :]

Comment: so can you write out the matrix representation of this T wrt the given basis (say in the 3-d case)?

Comment: I just tried and failed horribly. I guess I don't have a full grasp of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:
Let
$$
\mathbf{B}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
     1&     0\\
     0&     1\\
     0&     0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\mathbf{C}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
     0&     0\\
     1&     0\\
     0&     1\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Does $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}^{T}$ have the desired property?

More importantly, is the rationale behind this example clear?

We want to find a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ such that its nullspace is a subspace of its range. 
But the nullspace is a set of vectors orthogonal to the row space of $\mathbf{A}$ (or equivalently orthogonal to a basis of its row space).
Lets say that I choose first a basis for the row space. Let $\mathbf{C}^{T}$ be that choice as in the example above. Then $[1\, 0\, 0]^{T}$ will be in the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$. And in fact it spans the entire subspace (because in my example $\mathbf{C}$ has rank $2$).

Now, we need to make sure that $[1\, 0\, 0]^{T}$ is in the range of $\mathbf{A}$. It suffices to ensure that a basis of the nullspace is used to form a basis of the column space of $\mathbf{A}$.
Here I selected this basis to be the columns of $\mathbf{B}$ (which includes $[1\, 0\, 0]^{T}$).

Finally note that it is also important that both $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are full rank.

Comment: Yes it does! That's so cool. Would it be possible to inquire what was going on in your mind when you came up with the example?

Comment: I expanded the answer.